# My code to find no. of a substrings in a string. Why is j<=str.length() - 3 causing runtime error?

Tags: c++, string, string-length

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        
        int T;
        int count = 0;                                      
        cin>>T;
        
        for(int i = 0; i<T; i++) 
        {
            
            string str;
            cin>>str;
            count = 0;
```

---

- This part is for checking how many occurrences of "xyz" are there in my code.
- The test conditon j<=str.length() - 3 in for loop is causing error for some test case(s).
- When I run the for loop test condition j<=str.length() it does not give error.

  ```
           for(int j = 0;j<=str.length()-3; j++) 

           {   

               string x;
               x = str.substr(j, 3);
               if(x =="xyz")
               {   
                   count++;
               }
           }

           if(count) 
           {
              cout<<count<<endl;
           }
           else 
           {
              cout<<"-1"<<endl;
           }
       }
  return 0;
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String lengths use unsigned math; 2-3 becomes 2^64-1.  Try `j<-3 || j+3<=str.length()`